# .htaccess breaks CSS and Javascript when query-string is passed

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, path, url-rewriting

I have a problem with my .htaccess file.
This is my site structure

```
/root
   /SubFolder/  # I'm working on this one
      .htaccess
      index.php
      news.php
      /css/
         normalize.css
         main.css
      /js/
         scripts.js
      /admin/
         news.php
         add.php
         edit.php
```

Everything works fine except when I try to access the following url: `edit/2` ( this wold be the same as `edit.php?id=2` ) in the `admin` directory which is in the `SubDirectory`.

This is my .htaccess file

```
# ##############################################################################
# # URL REWRITES                                                               #
# ##############################################################################
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /SubFolder
    SetEnv WROOT /var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs/SubFolder/
</IfModule>

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Custom error messages / pages                                              |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ErrorDocument 404 /SubFolder/template/404.php

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Removing the "www." at the beginning of URLs                  |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment on live website
#<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
#   RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
#   RewriteRule ^ http%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
#</IfModule>


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Remove the slash                                                           |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Redirect to extensionless url                                              |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Pretty urls                                                                |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^edit/([0-9]+)$ edit.php?id=$1 [L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

When I try to go to `edit/2` in the `admin` directory, my styles, images and scripts paths are all broken. In fact the included path in the chrome console shows `http://website.com/SubFolder/admin/css/style.css` instead of `http://website.com/SubFolder/css/style.css`. If i go to a normal page without query-strings, in either the `SubDirectory` or the `SubDirectory/admin/` folder, my styles are loaded correctly.

Just for the record, this is how I include `<link>` and `<script>` in the `admin` directory: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/normalize.css">`

I tried to change the `RewriteBase` to just `/` and `/SubFolder/admin` but then all of my pages have broken paths.

I also tried to add `<base href="/admin/">` but still broken paths.

Any suggestions or help of how can I fix this ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try one the 2 ways to fix this:

1. Use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`. So your css links should be like this for example:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/SubFolder/admin/css/style.css">
   ```
2. If switching to absolute links is not an option then try inserting this rule as your **very first rule** in your current .htaccess:

   ```
   RewriteRule /((?:css|js|images)/.+)$ $1 [L,NC,R=301]
   ```

Comment: Unfortunately the 2nd method does not work, I get a 500 error and I cannot see the error log. I think I might use the absolute path even if to me it does not seem a very nice fix. Just so I can make myself clear, the admin/ folder is a 'sub-subfolder' of the root, the .htaccess is in the subfolder and the admin/ only has the pages, all the css, javascript and images are in the subfolder. The strange thing is that only when I use a query-string (admin/edit/2) this happens, normal pages (admin/news, admin/add) work just fine and also page.php?id=2. Thank you anyway

Comment: Yes that is due to another layer of directory that gets added by `admin/edit/2` since for relative URI structure you have `../css/...` it changes the context. Also note that for pretty URI scheme best option is to always use absolute URLs for css/js/images. I will try to tweak rewrite rule one more time but absolute URL is recommended option.

Comment: Still no luck, I'll go with the absolute path. One last question though, would it harm to put another .htaccess file in admin/, completely ignoring the one in the subfolder and write all the rules again specifically for the admin/ folder only ?

Comment: Sure that will be clean but isn't `admin` a sub directory under `SubFolder/`?

Comment: Sorry for replying this late. Yes it is, are you saying that I will have the same problem ?

Comment: No i didn't mean that. Use of absolute URLs as I suggested will definitely fix the problem. You can have a .htaccess in `/Subfolder/admin/` for admin specific URLs.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to add `<base href="/admin/">`, you want to add `<base href="/Subfolder/">`

Comment: Just tried this but the paths are still incorrect. This time it shows     http://website.com/css/style.css The SubFolder disappears completely from the path.